# access facebook page information

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I want to get facebook page about, description, location, basic info etc. I have got the access token for page. I am getting likes of page like this:

```
public void getLikes (String id,final TextView likes,final int position)
    {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("id", id);
        params.putString("fields", "likes");
        Request request = new Request(session, "search", params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject res = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject().getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0);
                    if (res.length()>1){
                        likes.setText(String.valueOf(res.getInt("likes")));
                        Preferences.data.getData().get(position).setLikes(String.valueOf(res.getInt("likes")));
                    }
                    else {
                        Preferences.data.getData().get(position).setLikes("No Likes");
                        likes.setText("0");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });
        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();
    }
```

If I add more parameters in bundle, I get the value of last parameter added, what should I do. Facebook's documentation about graph api is not much clear.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an issue specific to the API, you're just only using one field of the response (`.getJSONObject(0)`)

if you request multiple fields you need to look at each of them, currently you're only fetching the first

Comment: how should I add other fields ? what should be their key ?

Comment: You should debug the response you're getting and look at the fields, but it should match the documentation, if you ask for 'name' it'll be in the 'name' key of the data response